# Position from LLA to NED and vice-versa

Tags: convert

I have two points, `origin` and `point`, defined in Latitude (geodetic), longitude and altitude.

Now I want to convert `point` position in NED coordinates, using `origin` as center of the NED coordinate system.

What's the best way to perform this conversion?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by NED coordinates?

Comment: North-East-Down. They are similiar to ENU (East-North-Up). They are coordinate systems referred to local tangent plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation you want should be possible with GDAL cs2cs and a local transverse mercator projection. You can download GDAL from [Link](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php), but it is also availble for Linux and Mac OSX. It works in a terminal window.

The unusual axis order was introduced here:

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/axis-switch-to-control-axis-orientation-td3841902.html

```
cs2cs +proj=latlong +datum=WGS84 +to  +proj=tmerc +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +k_0=1 +lon_0=7 +lat_0=51 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +axis=ned +units=meter
7.05 51.05
```

lon_0 and lat_0 are the lonlat coordinates of your `origin` in decimal degrees, and the lonlat coordinates you enter in the next line are those of your `point`. Result is in meters.

```
D:\Karten\gdal\gdal-1-11>    cs2cs +proj=latlong +datum=WGS84 +to  +proj=tmerc +
ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +k_0=1 +lon_0=7 +lat_0=51 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +axis=ned +units=m
7.01 51.01
1112.53 701.83 -0.00
```

While the usual axis orientation delivers these values:

```
D:\Karten\gdal\gdal-1-11>    cs2cs +proj=latlong +datum=WGS84 +to  +proj=tmerc +
ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +k_0=1 +lon_0=7 +lat_0=51 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +units=m
7.01 51.01
701.83  1112.53 0.00
```

Vice-versa works the same way, just exchange the projection definitions before and after the `+to`.